# LOV query is invalid

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am working with APEX 4.2.1.00.08 and I keep getting the validation error "*LOV query is invalid, a display and a return value are needed, the column names need to be different. If your query contains an in-line query, the first FROM clause in the SQL statement must not belong to the in-line query.*". I'm not sure what's causing this. My sql is:

```
SELECT u1.name d, susu.subunitid r
FROM basic.subunitsuperunit susu
INNER JOIN basic.unit u1 ON susu.subunitid = u1.unitid
INNER JOIN basic.unit u2 ON susu.superunitid = u2.unitid
WHERE level = 3
AND u1.name != 'XYZ'
CONNECT BY PRIOR subunitid = superunitid
START WITH u1.name = (SELECT u3.name FROM basic.unit u3 WHERE u3.unitid = (SELECT TO_NUMBER(gp.value) FROM basic.global_parameters gp WHERE gp.name = 'A_UNIT'))
ORDER BY u1.name
```

I have made sure there was no semicolon, and I have checked this query in SQL Developer and it runs fine. I already realize those subqueries aren't optimal, but what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure why Apex is rejecting this query (the reasons given in the error message don't seem to apply), but my suggestion would be to create a view on this query, then select from the view for your LOV.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an apex_collection or a database view with your query and then create your lov based on the new object.
I too face same kind of difficulties with other queries and I always solved it so.

Answer (score 0):

This happens also if you begin your query using the WITH clause. You can wrap the whole lot up with 
`SELECT name d, ID r
From (your query here)`

Answer (score 0):

I see this post is old, but I ran into the same error in the "Lists of Values" portion of the application.  My issue happened to be that a grant was missing for the applicaton's run as user.